# Trouble creating and storing data for wave file using 2-D arrays

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, wav

Recently, I've been writing songs as wave files. However, I decided to try something new: use 2-D arrays. When I run my program, however, the wave file isn't playing anything. My intention is to create an array that consists of notes and store the array into the data portion of the wave file so that as the time goes by, different notes are playing (i.e. the notes I've assigned):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define A   440.00
#define As  466.16
#define B   493.88
#define C   523.25
#define Cs  554.37
#define D   587.33
#define Ds  622.25
#define E   659.25
#define F   698.46
#define Fs  739.99
#define G   783.99
#define Gs  830.61

int main() {
    FILE* fp;
    fp = fopen("song.wav", "wb");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("File does not exist.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    char ChunkID[4] = "RIFF", Format[4] = "WAVE", Subchunk1ID[4] = "fmt ", Subchunk2ID[4] = "data";
    unsigned int ChunkSize, Subchunk1Size, Subchunk2Size;
    unsigned short int AudioFormat, NumChannels, BlockAlign, BitsPerSample;
    int SampleRate, ByteRate;
    ChunkSize = 12 + 24 + 8 - 8 + 5 * 44100 * 2;
    Subchunk1Size = 16;
    AudioFormat = 1;
    NumChannels = 1;
    SampleRate = 44100;
    ByteRate = 2 * SampleRate;
    BitsPerSample = 16;
    BlockAlign = NumChannels * BitsPerSample / 8;
    Subchunk2Size = 9 * ByteRate;
    int i, j;
    short int audio[9][9] = {A, B, Cs, D, E, D, Cs, B, A};
    float freq, amplitude = 32700;
    for (i = 0; i < 9 * SampleRate; i++){
        for (j = 0; j == i; j++)
            freq = audio[i][j] * 2.0 * M_PI;  
        *audio[i] = amplitude * sin(freq * i / SampleRate);
    }
    fwrite(ChunkID, 4, 1, fp);
    fwrite(&ChunkSize, 4, 1, fp);
    fwrite(Format, 4, 1, fp);
    fwrite(Subchunk1ID, 4, 1, fp);
    fwrite(&Subchunk1Size, 4, 1, fp);
    fwrite(&AudioFormat, 2, 1, fp);
    fwrite(&NumChannels, 2, 1, fp);
    fwrite(&SampleRate, 4, 1, fp);
    fwrite(&ByteRate, 4, 1, fp);
    fwrite(&BlockAlign, 2, 1, fp);
    fwrite(&BitsPerSample, 2, 1, fp);
    fwrite(Subchunk2ID, 4, 1, fp);
    fwrite(&Subchunk2Size, 4, 1, fp);
    fwrite(audio, 2, 1, fp);
    fclose(fp);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: You should not use single-char `#defines`. As these are textual replcaements, they might appear in unexpected locations. Instead, use an 'enum' for constatns which belong together. Also note that using standard tyypes does not guarantee a specific size. Use `stdint.h` types instead and properly serialize,

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what tune you are trying to write to the wav. file, but a few initial errors:

```
short int audio[9][9] = {A, B, Cs, D, E, D, Cs, B, A};
```

this creates a 9x9 array with A, B, etc. stored in audio[0], and all other values initialized to 0. So later, you are trying to calculate frequencies, well most of your values from audio are 0.

```
  for (i = 0; i < 9 * SampleRate; i++){
```

Since `SampleRate = 44100`, you are going to step out of bounds of your `audio` array very quickly.

```
    *audio[i] = amplitude * sin(freq * i / SampleRate);
```

What this line does is it will store the computed value as an int in `audio[i][0]` after all is said and done. I'm not sure why you have a two dimensional array when you're not trying to do anything with it.

Happy debugging!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that I needed a separate array to store the data and then use a nested for loop to store the notes vs. time. Fixed it as such:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

#define A   440.00
#define As  466.16
#define B   493.88
#define C   523.25
#define Cs  554.37
#define D   587.33
#define Ds  622.25
#define E   659.25
#define F   698.46
#define Fs  739.99
#define G   783.99
#define Gs  830.61

int main() {
    struct WAVE {
        char ChunkID[4];
        unsigned int ChunkSize;
        char Format[4];
        char Subchunk1ID[4];
        unsigned int Subchunk1Size;
        unsigned short int AudioFormat;
        unsigned short int NumChannels;
        int SampleRate;
        int ByteRate;
        unsigned short int BlockAlign;
        unsigned short int BitsPerSample;
        char Subchunk2ID[4];
        unsigned int Subchunk2Size;
    };
    struct WAVE w;
    FILE* fp;
    fp = fopen("song.wav", "wb");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("File does not exist.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    strcpy(w.ChunkID, "RIFF");
    strcpy(w.Format, "WAVE");
    strcpy(w.Subchunk1ID, "fmt ");
    strcpy(w.Subchunk2ID, "data");
    w.Subchunk1Size = 16;
    w.AudioFormat = 1;
    w.NumChannels = 1;
    w.SampleRate = 44100;
    w.ByteRate = 2 * w.SampleRate;
    w.BitsPerSample = 16;
    w.BlockAlign = w.NumChannels * w.BitsPerSample / 8;
    short int audio[9][w.SampleRate / 3];
    float amplitude = 32700;
    int i, j, numnotes, numdatabytes;
    float f[12] = {A, As, B, C, Cs, D, Ds, E, F, Fs, G, Gs};
    int notes[9] = {1, 3, 5, 6, 8, 6, 5, 3, 1};
    numnotes = sizeof(notes) / 4;
    numdatabytes = numnotes * w.ByteRate / 3;
    for (j = 0; j < numnotes; j++) {
        for (i = 0; i < w.SampleRate / 3; i++)
            audio[j][i] = amplitude * sin(2 * M_PI * f[j] * i / w.SampleRate);
    }
    w.ChunkSize = 12 + 24 + 8 - 8 + numdatabytes;
    w.Subchunk2Size = numdatabytes;
    fwrite(&w, 44, 1, fp);
    for (i = 0; i < numnotes; i++)
        fwrite(audio[notes[i]], 2, w.SampleRate / 3, fp);
    fclose(fp);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```